# Dropdown list with a slide-down animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a button where I wants to implement a dropdown list upon the click action of it. Hence, that dropdown list should smoothly slide down (not pop-up) once the button is clicked. How can I achieve this. Once I did this feature in native IOS, but the fact I'm new to react-native I have troubles of understanding how to it. Any help with a code snippet would much appreciate.

Comment: Best way is to look around for different tutorials online. Try a bit of code yourself and then if it doesn't work as you want it to behave you can post a question here with code. 
Got a lot of different inspirations by just googling "dropdown react native"

Comment: all i found was pop-up type dropdown menus

Comment: Could you give me an example app or gif so I can understand what you need exactly?